# Robot's 360 deg rotation platform

Tags: robotics

I would like to construct a platform for my robot that can rotate in 360 degrees. 
I have stepper motor that is able to rotate so. 
The problem is I have some sensors and controllers placed on that platform so I need to power them up and read data from them. 
I need to have wires going from the lower unrotatible level of the robot to that platform.

Picture:
[image]

Any thoughts on how could I achieve something like this?

Comment: I answered your question, but this type of question may be better suited for either the Robotics or the Electrical Engineering stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your application, you will need something to transmit the electrical signals and power to your rotating platform.  Thankfully, there is a device called a slip ring which will do just this.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring):

[image: Slip Ring Diagram]

> A slip ring is an electromechanical device that allows the transmission of power and electrical signals from a stationary to a rotating structure. A slip ring can be used in any electromechanical system that requires rotation while transmitting power or signals. It can improve mechanical performance, simplify system operation and eliminate damage-prone wires dangling from movable joints.

You can find them from your favorite electronics vendor, but here is an example from [Adafruit, distributed by Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/736/1528-1152-ND/5353612?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_PLA_5353612).